# How to open Android market with uri in 1.5

Tags: android

How do I open the android market with uri in Android 1.5?

Answer (score 2):

You should send a Intent `ACTION_VIEW` with the intent data as marketplace URI.

Look at these links, I think this is what you are looking for:

[First link](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent)

[Second link](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/publishing/publishing.html)

and if you just want to start other app from yours, [they look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application).